# Solr indexing structure with MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr

I have three to five search fields in my application and planning to integrate this with Apache Solr. I tried to do the sams with a single table and is working fine. Here are my questions.

1. Can we create index multiple tables in same core ? Or should i create separate core for each indexes (i guess this concept is wrong).
2. Suppose i have 4 tables users, careers, education and location. I have two search boxes in a php page where one is to search for simple locations (just like an autocomplete box) and another one is to get search for a keyword which should check on tables careers and education. If multiple indexes are possible under single core; 
    2.1 How do we define the query here ?
    2.2 Can we specify index name in query (like table name in mysql) ?

Links which can answer my concerns are enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting to query the same data as part of the same request, such as auto-completing users, educations and locations at the same time, indexing them to the same core is probably what you want.

The term "core" is probably identical to the term "index" in your usage, and having multiple sets of data in the same index will usually be achieved through having a field that indicates the type of document (and then applying a filter query if you want to get documents of only one type, such as `fq=type:location`. You can use [the grouping feature of Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) to get separate result sets of documents back for each query as well.

If you're only ever going to query the data separately, having them in separate indexes are probably the way to go, as you'll be able to scale and perform analysis and tuning independent from each index in that case (and avoid having to always have a filter query to get the type of content you're looking for).

Specifying the index name is the same as specifying the core, and is part of the URL to Solr: `http://localhost:8983/solr/index1/` or `http://localhost:8983/solr/index2/`.